# Segmentation fault when linking math.h library in Clion wsl

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, clion, wsl-2

I have wrote the following program which using math.h library (in the function count_lines, im using ceil and log10 functions).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

void count_lines(short unsigned int G);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    count_lines(18);
    return 0;
}

void count_lines(short unsigned int G) {
    int status,g=0;
    pid_t pid;

    do{
        pid = fork();
        if(pid ==0)
            g++;

    }while(g<G && pid ==0 );
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    int num_of_digits = ceil(log10(g) +1);
    char* command = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen("grep \"generation is ") + num_of_digits +strlen("\" out.txt ") + strlen("| wc -l")+1));
    sprintf(command,"grep \"generation is %d\" out.txt| wc -l", g);
    printf("%s\n" , command);
}
```

I am using clion wsl and in order to link math library I used the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(HW1 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
add_executable(HW1 main.c)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} m)
```

When I run the program I get segmentation fault:

```
grep "generation is 18" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 17" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 16" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 15" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 14" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 13" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 12" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 11" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 10" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 9" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 8" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 7" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 6" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 5" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 4" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 3" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 2" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 1" out.txt| wc -l
/bin/bash: line 1:  5353 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) /mnt/c/Users/itzik/Documents/OperatingSystems/HW1/cmake-build-debug/HW1

Process finished with exit code 139
```

If I dont use math.h functions and replace num_of_digits with some constant number, it works fine and I get the desirable output:

```
grep "generation is 18" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 17" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 16" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 15" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 14" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 13" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 12" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 11" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 10" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 9" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 8" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 7" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 6" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 5" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 4" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 3" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 2" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 1" out.txt| wc -l
grep "generation is 0" out.txt| wc -l

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So I guess the segmentation fault occurs when we are trying to read ceil/log10 from the header.

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `math.h` is not a library.  It is a header.

Comment: `log10(0)` is going to give you a pole error. Try `log10(g + 1)`

Comment: @WilliamPursell That actually solved the segmentation fault. Thanks!